# Typescript and jQuery type. The right way to import jquery type?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is it possible to include jquery.d.ts and use jQueryStatic type? I need something like

```
...
protected el : jQueryStatic;
...
```

No matter how I try I can not import jQueryStatic interface from https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/jquery

Thanks a lot.

**Update**

```
/// <reference path="../../../../defs/jquery.d.ts" />
 error TS2304: Cannot find name 'jQuery'.

/// <reference path="../../../../defs/jquery.d.ts" />
import {jQuery} from 'jquery';
error TS2305: Module '"jquery"' has no exported member 'jQuery'.
```

**Update**

Working solution was to add type JQuery not jQuery.

```
/// <reference path="../../../defs/jquery.d.ts" />
...
protected $el: JQuery;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on your code :

```
el : jQueryStatic
```

Since you used `el` I think you meant `element` and by that the correct interface is actually `JQuery`:

```
el : JQuery
```

### But the question you asked for

You can use `typeof` to convert a variable into a type. More : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/declarationspaces.html

## Update

The JQuery (not the case) is declared globally. The following works fine:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
var el:JQuery;
```